# Slow connecting to EE

Tags: ee2

I have a user complaining of slow connection to EE. It happens when the user clones an entry. It sometimes times out, sometimes it's just very slow. This is a homepage entry and it gets cloned frequently. Any thoughts?

Comment: What do you mean by 'cloning' an entry? I'd start by enabling the output profiler (admin->system administration-> output and debugging) and seeing where the bottleneck lies. Then get back here and report :)

Comment: Does this slowness happen no matter where they are connecting from? For example,  have they tried from home as well as at the office.

Comment: I have an the Zenbu MX Cloner installed that allows you to clone entries. I plan on turning on debugging and seeing if there is a bottleneck, I'll report back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just an idea, but are you using NSM add-on updater? I have slow loading when this add-on gets stuck on when checking for an update. Alternatively , try disabling some accessories if you using any others.

Comment: Check all add-ons, especially accessories. I once had the same thing and the problem turned out to be the Health Check add-on.

Comment: Any add-on doing a request to a third party web service is one of the first places I look - could be an SMTP server, or NSM add-on updater, etc.